# Understanding FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I found this code online and am trying to test it out in my project. My project uses a database and I want to swipe between each record so I think ViewPager is the way to go. I have my activity and fragments already working but I have no clue how to implement the attached code into my project. What I'm looking for is where and how do I use this? From the activity or the fragment? and how do I go about doing it. I already have a cursor and the projection but now really sure how the two work together. I hope I'm making sense.

```
public class CursorPagerAdapter<F extends Fragment> extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final Class<F> fragmentClass;
    private final String[] projection;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public CursorPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Class<F> fragmentClass, String[] projection, Cursor cursor) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        this.projection = projection;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public F getItem(int position) {
        if (cursor == null) // shouldn't happen
            return null;

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        F frag;
        try {
            frag = fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        for (int i = 0; i < projection.length; ++i) {
            args.putString(projection[i], cursor.getString(i));
        }
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (cursor == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        if (cursor == c)
            return;

        this.cursor = c;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've to use this in your `MainAcitivity` here along with the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you're passing the `projection` and `cursor` to the constructor. Before setting the adapter to the `viewPager` pass the necessaries to this `CusorPagerAdapter`

Comment: I appreciate the help. How do I declare the constructor?

Comment: Create a new instance for that class `CusrorPagerAdapter` before setting the adapter. so that you can pass the arguments

Comment: Like this: ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
   fragment.setArguments(arguments);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
   
   ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   CursorPagerAdapter<ItemDetailFragment> adapterViewPager = new CursorPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null, null, null);
         vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

Comment: Yeah.. why don't you pass your arguments... It should be like this `CursorPagerAdapter<ItemDetailFragment> adapterViewPager = new CursorPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment_class, your_projection, your_cursor);`

Comment: Yeah, I was just showing you what I was doing. I think I'm getting it now. Thanks a bunch for the help. Why don't you make and answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49023/discussion-between-sha-and-michael-little)

Comment: On more question. where to I get fragment_class from? thanks!

Comment: that is your list of fragments you're gonna use for the `ViewPager`

Comment: @sha I hate to be a pain but I'm just not getting it. How am I supposed to create this list? From the number of records in the cursor? Can you please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you've to modify your code

```
ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
CursorPagerAdapter<ItemDetailFragment> adapterViewPager = new CursorPagerAdapter(
    getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment_class, your_projection, your_cursor);
vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```